# Should I move wp-admin to a separated server? How to do it?

Tags: wp-admin, server

**A problem:**

My company has many employees who work in wp-admin, but the speed of work is not fast enough because of slow wp-admin loading.

**What did we try?**

We optimized wp-admin (plugins, queries, processes and etc.), but there is a need to achieve the best result.

My idea is to separate wp-admin. Why? Because now front-end and back-end use the same traffic. When front-end goes down because of many visitors online, back-end also becomes unavailable. We need wp-admin 100% available.

Should we host wp-admin on another server and how to do it? Is "two sites - one database" is the right way?

Comment: It's possible that the database itself is what is the bottleneck, especially if traffic is high. You would need to profile your server and determine where the bottleneck is to know if this will actually improve things. Until you know why the frontend fails you can't solve this or scale up as you don't know what it is you're scaling up. For example your site may be limited because your frontend has a very high memory consumption preventing multiple parallel requests, or it could be that you rely heavily on page builders and post meta queries, in which case your second server would be useless

Comment: With that in mind, i don't believe it's possible to answer this canonically and factually given the available information. There are too many unknowns, and it looks more like a discussion topic. Narrow it down to a specific question that can be answered factually